# Trouble with mv and adding the date

Tags: shell, rename, filenames, variable-substitution

I want to be able to move $oldfile to my backup folder and add the date to the file name. So I tried this...

```
mv $oldfile /home/u0146121/backupfiles/$oldfile_$(date +%F-%T)
```

This just gives me this output filename. (no orignal filename)

2013-07-11-10:22:25

Then I realized the potential problem for the above method. I have a while read loop that reads through a text file of path names for other files I wanted to compare. So for example, $oldfile is actually =

```
 $ cat oldfiles.txt
 /home/u0146121/OldLogFiles/file2.txt
```

**So**... I want to be able to move the file2.txt and just keep the file2.txt name and add the date to it as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The shell sees the variable `$oldfile_` which is undefined. You can fix that by using `${oldfile}_` instead.

But, do you really want to keep the paths to the old file? If not, use

```
mv $oldfile /home/u0146121/backupfiles/${oldfile##*/}_$(date +%F-%T)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to adding a time stamp when moving files in bash

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd "FILES_LOCATION"
COPYDIR="NEW_FILE_LOCATION"

for file in *.FILE_EXTENSION; do
        NEWAPPEND=$(date +%s)
        cp $file "$COPYDIR"/"$NEWAPPEND"$file
        rm $file
done
```